# Fingerprint Activation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, 18.04

I have a [HP Elitebook 2530P](http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2008/mobility/ds_elitebook2530p.pdf).
I have a problem to activate the fingerprint sensor for the login. can anybody help me? I use Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you tried some driver for your fingerprint?

Comment: yes, but i cant find the ubuntu version for the elitebook

Answer (score 25):

I did this on my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 - dell vostro:

Install the applications needed:

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

You may want to change the PAM configuration to use fingerprint for sudo:
And check the Fingerprint authentication option. So when you use sudo it will ask to fingerprint. If you wait the fingerprint timeout it will ask for standard password.

Reboot
Then go to settings/users and enable the Fingerprint Login. You may need to reboot.

Comment: this thing didn't work for ThinkPad series

Comment: It is still not working for me.  I have selected the fingerprint sensor in the pam-auth-update.  But it is still not available to enable on the Users screen.

Comment: Same here, didn't work. using asus a509fj..

Comment: Works on my asus P2440UA

Comment: It works without any issues on my ThinkPad T440p running 18.04 LTS. I just made sure to reboot after installation and then go to user details to enable and sign up my fingerprint.

Comment: you can select and deselect the option using spacebar and navigate using the arrow keys

Comment: There is nothing about fingerprints in Admin/Users

Comment: Good that it works for you.
however it would really helpful to know the fingerprint sensor ID. 
"works for me" is not helping others without the relevant details 
you can get the fingerprint device id e.g.like this
    lsusb  | grep print
mine is
us 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
and NOT working

Answer (score 11):

I have not tested the answers that [Satria H R Harsono links to](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049529/606758), but I noticed that those require the use of a PPA. My solution should get you up and running without the PPA. Even better, you don't have to hit enter or the login button after swiping your finger. It just logs in automatically.

First of all, make sure that your fingerprint reader is recognized. These typically show up as USB devices. Run `lsusb`

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
...
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0483:2016 STMicroelectronics Fingerprint Reader
...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can see that my system  detects my attached fingerprint reader as an STMicroelectronics Fingerprint Reader. From here all I need to do is install some programs and modify a configuration file.

- Install the applications needed.

  ```
  sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
  ```
- Once install finishes, open /etc/pam.d/common-auth for editing (`sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth`). Find the line (line 17 on my system) that reads

  ```
  auth   [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
  ```

  and modify the file adding the line shown below in bold. Make sure the order of these lines is the same as shown here.

  ```
  auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10
  auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
  ```

  Save the file (Ctrl+Shift+X, Y, Enter).
- Finally, enroll your fingerprint with the following command

  ```
  fprintd-enroll $USER
  ```

  After running the command, swipe your finger across the reader 3 times to enroll your fingerprint.

That's all there is to it. You should now be able to use your fingerprint reader to log in or to authenticate (for things like installations) post-login.

Comment: Works like a charm on old DigitalPersona 4000B!!! Also using the Fingerprint GUI works: https://askubuntu.com/a/872187/139248

Answer (score 3):

I've just configured Elan's fingerprint device on my Xiaomi Notebook Pro under Ubuntu 18.04 with latest upgrades. Official version of `libfprint` which coming with Ubuntu is not supporting Elan's device, so I use to build [iafilatov's](https://github.com/iafilatov) version. Maybe it can be useful for HP 2530 by changing vendor ID according to lsusb's output following this manual.

> In my case fingerprint-gui crashes on successful verification with iafilatov's libfprint, so I am using fprintd utilities only

- [Install fprintd and enable it for sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092947/645447)

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
  sudo pam-auth-update
  ```
- Update `libfprint` building and **installing** [iafilatov's libfprint](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint). See [README.md](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint/blob/elan-github-msg/README.md) for build **release** version.
- Update symbolic link `/usr/lib/libfprint.so.0` -> `/usr/local/lib/libfprint.so.0.0.0` (to the newly installed iafilatov's build.
- Allow fingerprint enrolling to user as follows:

  1. Create [/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libfprint0-custom.rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365534) as follows:

     ```
     ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c1a", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
     ```

     > Vendor & product IDs can be found in `lsusb` output, search for Elan line smth like `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp.`
  2. Add your `$USER` to `plugdev` group:

     ```bsh
     usermod -a -G plugdev $USER
     ```
  3. Reboot
- Enroll fingerprints:

  ```bsh
  fprintd-enroll
  ```
- Verify fingerprint matching

  ```bsh
  fprintd-verify
  ```
- Done. You can check it by calling `sudo` or while Ubuntu session login (may need reboot):
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you refer to use your fingerprint reader in Ubuntu for login? I think you missed this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/872187/275849

Or do you prefer to use your fingerprint reader for any authentication? Check this out https://askubuntu.com/a/1040609/275849