# How to configure an Elan fingerprint scanner on an Asus UX430A laptop?

Tags: drivers, usb, asus, scanner, elantech

I have an [ASUS UX430UA](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX430UA/HelpDesk_Download/) and [lsusb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lsusb.8.html) shows the fingerprint scanner is an Elan Microelectronics Corp.

I'm new to the Linux world in general and Ubuntu. I read a few threads and tried out some of the solutions posted but couldn't get it to work. Can someone help me install it and make it work? (remember I'm new and have no idea how to install things and clueless about what I'm doing when I type in the terminal)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fingerprint Activation on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: It  is not guaranteed that the scanner is supported in linux.

Comment: @Nicolas Strucelj Sadly, Asus does not provide Linux drivers support. However, as Pilot6 kindly noted above, https://askubuntu.com/a/1133528/197910 may (repeat, may) work. You're doing fine; you had the wits to use lsusb to find the device details, which shows you will do OK.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to follow those steps that I had found before posting this question, but I'm stuck cause I don't know how to so these steps:   Update libfprint building and installing iafilatov's libfprint. See README.md for build release version.
And
Update symbolic link /usr/lib/libfprint.so.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libfprint.so.0.0.0 (to the newly installed iafilatov's build.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 is bundled with version 0.82 which doesn't support Elan fingerprint reader.

Version 0.99 supports Elan chip and can be built on Ubuntu 18.04 V1 uses Glib V2.57 when Ubuntu 18.04 latest glib's version is 2.56.

When I tried v0.99, even if the device was supported, one tenth of fingerprint readings were successful. might be a "finger" problem though ;)

iafilatov in his github says that his fork is now behind forked repository and we should use the origin. In order to use compiled version, symlinks needs to be created:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfprint.so.0.0.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libfprint.so.0.0.0  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfprint.so.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libfprint.so.0.0.0
```

Please adapt according to your system, as it may be different.