# 19.10: Enable Asus VivoBook S13 S330FA fingerprint reader

Tags: drivers, usb, asus

I just bought a notebook ([Asus VivoBook S13 S330FA](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S13-S330FA/Tech-Specs/)) to use with Ubuntu (19.10). Everything works splendid except the fingerprint reader.
I'm trying to see if there is a chance to make this work somehow, but I cannot figure out what kind of reader I have.
Asus support cannot tell me the model for some reason, but they provided me with the Windows drivers:

```
Fingerprint_DCH_ELAN_Win10_64_VER451300110010.zip
Fingerprint_DCH_Goodix_Win10_64_VER1020900.zip
```

So it's either Elan, or Goodix. Which one, again, "cannot be known" by ASUS. I figured I should be able to check that with lsusb, but sadly I cannot see it. Am I supposed to see it?
This is the output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta 2.4G Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How would you start with such a problem? I would appricate any help/pointers.

Tamás

Comment: They can't tell you because they don't know. Manufacturers source multiple vendors for components, and their at-the-factory Windows image installs sense the hardware and adapt automagically. Did it come with Windows 10 and if so is it still installed? If so, take a look in Device Manager.

Comment: PS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04/1133528#1133528 or https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/No-driver-for-fingerprint-scanner-Goodix-GF3208-on-Linux/m-p/6242579 may, repeat, may work. However, shocked that is does not appear with lsusb.

Comment: The notebook came with no OS. I'll try the links you provided when I get home.

Comment: Well, these posts all assume that the device shows up in lsusb, so I guess this won't work here :S I think I should test it in Windows (can it be a HW issue?), but I really don't want to install it. I wonder if I can create a live Windows stick...

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l6Oz27sUFxk

Comment: Thanks for the video :) So I tried Windows. Out-of-the-box there were some unknown PCI devices, so I installed the chipset driver update, provided by ASUS, and the fingerprint reader appeared in Device Manager fine. It's an Elan device (Elan WBF fingerprint sensor), and according to windows it's "location" is Intel(R) Serial IO SPI Host Controller - 9DAA

Comment: So I checked my Ubuntu for spi devices and I found this:
`/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi-ELAN7001:00`
So I guess the kernel knows about the device. Is there any support for an spi fingerprint reader in Ubuntu?

Comment: I've been working on a driver for these kinds of sensors (elan spi) over at https://github.com/mincrmatt12/elan-spi-fingerprint.

Comment: This is awesome that you do that! I am trying it out now. At the moment I'm stuck with the proto (frozen at "Capturing image"), but there is hope! :) I'll write about this on github!