# ubuntu 20.10 fingerprint reader

Tags: fingerprint-reader, 20.10

neither lsusb nor lspci lists it, in windows device manager it shows up as ELAN WBF Fingerprint Sensor and its "Location" on Intel(R) Serial IO SPI Host Controller - 9DAA

```
ls /sys/bus/spi/devices/
spi-ELAN7001:00
```

Comment: same with no answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210321/19-10-enable-asus-vivobook-s13-s330fa-fingerprint-reader  Github: https://github.com/mincrmatt12/elan-spi-fingerprint and that is all so I doubt you will get it working at this time. I would suggest to file a bugreport to get support for it.

Comment: is this the same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04/1133528#1133528 ? No mention of the device but might be worth a shot

Comment: Here how to see if your fingerprint  device is supported https://askubuntu.com/questions/982593/unable-to-use-fingerprint-sensor-on-asus-vivobook-pro