# How can I enable biometric log in option on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, login, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I have a fingerprint scanner sensor on my laptop to sign in more conveniently. (Lenovo Ideapad 520)

The feature works fine on Windows but here on Ubuntu 18.04, I think I should download some drivers manually which is not provided by the manufacturer on their website. They only have windows drivers.

Do you know a way to activate this feature?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1092947/925971

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may give it a try to using package fwupd for installation of Windows Drivers on Ubuntu.

[According to itsfoss:](https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/)

> fwupd is an open source daemon that handles firmware upgrades in Linux based systems. It is created by GNOME developer Richard Hughes. Developers from Dell also contributed to the development of this open source tool.
> Basically, it utilizes the LVFS, Linux Vendor Firmware Service. Hardware vendors upload redistributable firmware to the LVFS site and thanks to fwupd, you can upgrade those firmware from inside the operating system itself. fwupd is supported by major Linux distributions like Ubuntu and Fedora.

Lenovo is one of the most contributing vendor member of LVFS and I believe I had seen several Synaptic Fingerprint drivers available for Lenovo but I'm not sure if it's available for IdeaPads, maybe the Synaptic Fingerprint Driver for other Lenovo products would work if it's not available directly for IdeaPad. You may try.

You may control if the equilavent Linux drivers exist or being developed from [here.](https://fwupd.org/)
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried. It is not working. I guess there isn't any proper driver for this. Also, I tried a lot and surfed all the solutions that were out there to fix my microphone and it did not work either.  Long story short, I gave up on my Linux standalone installation and went back to Windows. The WSL on windows fits my needs and I don't have to deal with driver software issues anymore. Sadly manufacturers don't provide Linux computers with enough driver software support.