# Fingerprint reader on Ubuntu 20.04 at HP ENVY 17m-CG0013DX

Tags: 20.04, hp, fingerprint-reader

This is the Reader on my laptop:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
```

And I can't find an step by step way to make it work on Ubuntu.

In [Fingerprint Activation on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04/1092947#1092947), they talk about iafilatov's libfprint for a ELAN reader on a HP laptop, but don't specify exactly what to do for a regular user (and not an IT professional) such as me.

So I couldn't really make it work, since I couldn't understand what to do and there is no option on Settings to enable or disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445458/ubuntu-22-04-fingerprint-sensor-04f30c4c-elan-microelectronics-corp-hp-envy), the drivers for this device are now available, but require building `libfprint` from source, using [this fork](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint/-/tree/elanmoc2). I was able to get this to work for my HP Envy with the same fingerprint reader and Ubuntu 22.04 by using

```
sudo apt-get install meson ninja-build libgusb-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libnss3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev gtk-doc-tools valgrind
sudo ldconfig
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint.git
cd libfprint/
git checkout elanmoc2
git pull
meson build
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

[You may need to reset your fingerprint reader in the BIOS](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint/-/issues/1)  — I could not verify my right index finger until I reset the reader, but all my other fingerprints worked. To reset the reader, enter the BIOS, look under Security, and enable “Fingerprint Reset on Reboot”. Select “Yes” when asked to verify that you want to reset the reader — you will lose all current fingerprint data — and allow the computer to reboot. The BIOS setting will reset to “No”, so you do not need to re-enter the BIOS.

Now you can login and add fingerprints using Settings/Users or `fprintd-enroll -f <finger>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Not Possible

Sorry, but this driver doesn't have Linux support and will never likely have because the vendor doesn't support it.

You can see the driver support in this website - [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/wiki/-/wikis/Unsupported%20Devices)

I also have a HP Pavillion laptop and my fingerprint scanner doesn't work in Linux. But no problem, that's just optional.