# Lubuntu login with fingerprint

Tags: lubuntu, fingerprint-reader

does anybody know how to enable fingerprint login in a LUBUNTU LXQT 0.14.1?
I have a Lenovo X230
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Run `lsusb` and edit your question with the line corresponding to your fingerprint reader.