# Login problem autotyped characters

Tags: login-screen, 20.10

I am using ubuntu 20.10 and I am trying to setup a usb fingerprint reader on my laptop.

I followed this thread : [Fingerprint Activation on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04/1133528#1133528)

updated my system with sudo apt update and upgrade

Reboted the beast and then, at login I could only typed 2 characters of my password until validating ... Impossible to login on my system ...

I tried to launch the terminal with ctrl + alt + F3, but when it asks  for my login, my login doesn't work, it reports "Login Incorrect"

How can I get out of this rabbit hole ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved it.

I had desactivated by mistake the SSH and UNIX login using the command :

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

And had to restart holding shift key, run the command in the terminal, reactivate UNIX and SSH and reboot to solve it.