# How to use fingerprint login in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader, pam

I have tried it using this commands:

> lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5301 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader**
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:568a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think it even detected my hardware. But when I do this.

> sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd

> fprintd-enroll

I am getting this error

> list_devices failed: No devices available

I even did the pam update as shown in this link.
[Fingerprint Activation on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04/1082465#1082465)

**Update**: I have come to know that fprint is not supprted for ID 27c6:5301.

Is there any other way to use fingerprint reader ?

Comment: It seems from the many questions I have seen a lot of this China stuff has no drivers and does not work.