# How to setup fingerprint login on dell inspiron 5370

Tags: 18.04, login, dell, security, fingerprint-reader

I have a  **dell inspiron 5370** laptop.

But I don't know how to setup fingerprint login on my Ubuntu Desktop 18.04  laptop!

Please guide how to setup :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into it but I do not think there is driver support for the Goodix Finger Print scanner in Linux yet, and was being discussed [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234844).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

and enable `Fingerprint authentication`

Further instructions on this  [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040609/790920).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a code for Goodix fingerprint sensor. That code is mainly written for Android devices. I have tried to compile it for Ubuntu 19.04. This code would be helpful to write a new driver. This code is written for the SPI interface. It would be useful if someone can try to rewrite this code for the USB interface.

https://github.com/adnanjee/Goodix-GF3208