# Avoid having to press any key to unlock screen [20.04]

Tags: login-screen

When opening up my laptop (dell xps) from sleep, I would like to be able to just tap the power button for fingerprint login and get straight into my desktop.

Currently there's a lock screen with the time on it and I need to press a key or a mouse press to get to the password/fp login.

How can I disable this screen?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open `Settings`, and goto `Users` open `Automatic Login` for your account. Then anytime you lock the screen, you will enter the login screen directly (No need to select user anymore).

Comment: This may help you as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015416/use-fingerprint-authentication-not-only-for-login. I wonder why they did not make it as default configuration.